# Let $R,S$ commutative rings and $I$ ideal of $R$ and $J$ ideal of $S$ Prove that $ I \times J$ is ideal of $R\times S$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $R,S$ commutative rings and $I$ ideal of $R$ and $J$ ideal of $S$

Prove that $ I \times J$ is ideal of $R\times S$

At first $I \times J$ is not empty since it contains $(0_R,0_S)$

Could someone help me continue? For $a,b \in I\times J, r\in \mathbb{R}$ i want to prove that $a-b\in I\times J$
And that $ar=ra \in I\times J$

1. Probably a duplicate

Comment: Hint : how are addition, subtraction and multiplication defined on the product ring $R\times S$ ?

Comment: @SolubleFish the first is fairly simple, how do i prove that $ar=(a_1 * r_1,a_2 * r_2) \in I\times J$ Edit: I took $a=(a_1,a_2)$ and the same for r

Comment: Well, $r_1 \in I$ so $a_1r_1 \in I$ and similarly, $a_2r_2\in J$.